# Redmine Calendar view not working

Tags: mysql, calendar, redmine

I have successfully installed Redmine on a Debian 7 box. The environment is:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                2.5.1.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.17
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Git                            1.7.10.4
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  scrum                          0.5.0
```

The problem is that when I click on the "Calendar" tab, I get the following error:

> 500 An error occurred while executing the query and has been logged. Please report this error to your Redmine administrator.

I looked at the Apache logs and this is what it says:

> Query::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'start_date' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT `issues`.`id` AS t0_r0, `issues`.`tracker_id` AS t0_r1, `issues`.`project_id` AS t0_r2, `issues`.`subject` AS t0_r3, `issues`.`description` AS t0_r4, `issues`.`due_date` AS t0_r5, `issues`.`category_id` AS t0_r6, `issues`.`status_id` AS t0_r7, `issues`.`assigned_to_id` AS t0_r8, `issues`.`priority_id` AS t0_r9, `issues`.`fixed_version_id` AS t0_r10, `issues`.`author_id` AS t0_r11, `issues`.`lock_version` AS t0_r12, `issues`.`created_on` AS t0_r13, `issues`.`updated_on` AS t0_r14, `issues`.`start_date` AS t0_r15, `issues`.`done_ratio` AS t0_r16, `issues`.`estimated_hours` AS t0_r17, `issues`.`parent_id` AS t0_r18, `issues`.`root_id` AS t0_r19, `issues`.`lft` AS t0_r20, `issues`.`rgt` AS t0_r21, `issues`.`is_private` AS t0_r22, `issues`.`closed_on` AS t0_r23, `issues`.`sprint_id` AS t0_r24, `issues`.`position` AS t0_r25, `projects`.`id` AS t1_r0, `projects`.`name` AS t1_r1, `projects`.`description` AS t1_r2, `projects`.`homepage` AS t1_r3, `projects`.`is_public` AS t1_r4, `projects`.`parent_id` AS t1_r5, `projects`.`created_on` AS t1_r6, `projects`.`updated_on` AS t1_r7, `projects`.`identifier` AS t1_r8, `projects`.`status` AS t1_r9, `projects`.`lft` AS t1_r10, `projects`.`rgt` AS t1_r11, `projects`.`inherit_members` AS t1_r12, `projects`.`product_backlog_id` AS t1_r13, `issue_statuses`.`id` AS t2_r0, `issue_statuses`.`name` AS t2_r1, `issue_statuses`.`is_closed` AS t2_r2, `issue_statuses`.`is_default` AS t2_r3, `issue_statuses`.`position` AS t2_r4, `issue_statuses`.`default_done_ratio` AS t2_r5, `trackers`.`id` AS t3_r0, `trackers`.`name` AS t3_r1, `trackers`.`is_in_chlog` AS t3_r2, `trackers`.`position` AS t3_r3, `trackers`.`is_in_roadmap` AS t3_r4, `trackers`.`fields_bits` AS t3_r5, `users`.`id` AS t4_r0, `users`.`login` AS t4_r1, `users`.`hashed_password` AS t4_r2, `users`.`firstname` AS t4_r3, `users`.`lastname` AS t4_r4, `users`.`mail` AS t4_r5, `users`.`admin` AS t4_r6, `users`.`status` AS t4_r7, `users`.`last_login_on` AS t4_r8, `users`.`language` AS t4_r9, `users`.`auth_source_id` AS t4_r10, `users`.`created_on` AS t4_r11, `users`.`updated_on` AS t4_r12, `users`.`type` AS t4_r13, `users`.`identity_url` AS t4_r14, `users`.`mail_notification` AS t4_r15, `users`.`salt` AS t4_r16, `users`.`must_change_passwd` AS t4_r17, `enumerations`.`id` AS t5_r0, `enumerations`.`name` AS t5_r1, `enumerations`.`position` AS t5_r2, `enumerations`.`is_default` AS t5_r3, `enumerations`.`type` AS t5_r4, `enumerations`.`active` AS t5_r5, `enumerations`.`project_id` AS t5_r6, `enumerations`.`parent_id` AS t5_r7, `enumerations`.`position_name` AS t5_r8, `sprints`.`id` AS t6_r0, `sprints`.`name` AS t6_r1, `sprints`.`description` AS t6_r2, `sprints`.`start_date` AS t6_r3, `sprints`.`end_date` AS t6_r4, `sprints`.`user_id` AS t6_r5, `sprints`.`project_id` AS t6_r6, `sprints`.`created_on` AS t6_r7, `sprints`.`updated_on` AS t6_r8, `sprints`.`is_product_backlog` AS t6_r9 FROM `issues` INNER JOIN `issue_statuses` ON `issue_statuses`.`id` = `issues`.`status_id` INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `issues`.`project_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `trackers` ON `trackers`.`id` = `issues`.`tracker_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `issues`.`assigned_to_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `enumerations` ON `enumerations`.`id` = `issues`.`priority_id` AND `enumerations`.`type` IN ('IssuePriority') LEFT OUTER JOIN `sprints` ON `sprints`.`id` = `issues`.`sprint_id` WHERE (projects.status <> 9 AND projects.id IN (SELECT em.project_id FROM enabled_modules em WHERE em.name='issue_tracking')) AND ((issues.status_id IN (SELECT id FROM issue_statuses WHERE is_closed=0)) AND projects.id IN (1,2)) AND (((start_date BETWEEN '2014-03-30' AND '2014-05-03') OR (due_date BETWEEN '2014-03-30' AND '2014-05-03')))

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql2::Error: Column 'start_date' in where clause is ambiguous:

when you will get this error is when plugins which have same column name of redmine column name .

eg:start_date

plugins list

1.scrum
2.holidays

these two plugins have same column name start_date.

so one solution is 
1. go to calendars.controller and find this line

events += @query.issues(:include => [:tracker, :assigned_to, :priority],
                              :conditions => ["((**start_date** BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (due_date BETWEEN ? AND ?))", @calendar.startdt, @calendar.enddt, @calendar.startdt, @calendar.enddt]
                              )

in this line change start_date  to issues.start_date.

so should look like this..

events += @query.issues(:include => [:tracker, :assigned_to, :priority],
                              :conditions => ["((**issues.start_date** BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (due_date BETWEEN ? AND ?))", @calendar.startdt, @calendar.enddt, @calendar.startdt, @calendar.enddt]
                              )

restart server......

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the redmine/app/controller/calendar_controller.rb file.

Add issues before start_date and due_date like this:

events += @query.issues(:include => [:tracker, :assigned_to, :priority],
                              :conditions => ["((issues.start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (issues.due_date BETWEEN ? AND ?))", @calendar.startdt, @calendar.enddt, @calendar.startdt, @calendar.enddt]
                              )

and restart Redmine.

Comment: Nine months later and I still see the same problem in redmine 2.6.1-stable